# Is it best practise to set a default state then overwrite with useEffect if default state is potentially unreachable

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next-router

I'm working with Nextjs and Next-Router, I have a side bar which indicates where you are in the application. The highlighted key on the sider is set by setting defaultSelectedKey which is a state like so:

```
    const [selectedMenuItem, setSelectedMenuItem] = useState(...);
```

It's important this selected key is correct as otherwise it can indicate you're in a different section of the application, specifically on refresh where the current state is lost.

I can get the state either by setting it is '1' and then running a use effect that sets it again like so:

```
    useEffect((): void => {
        const item = items.find((item) => item.route === router.pathname)
        setSelectedMenuItem(item!.key)
    }, [])
```

or I can do it directly in the state initiation like so:

```
    const [selectedMenuItem, setSelectedMenuItem] = useState((items.find((item) => item.route === router.pathname))!.key);
```

Is there any benefits / drawbacks to either method? What is best practise in this scenario?

Comment: Well the benefit of not using the effect is that you will get one less render.   Looking at what you have posted, the useEffect is just wasting time / resources.

Comment: Good point, something just felt wrong about so much happening when the state is being initialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either approach, but the drawback with setting the default state through the `useEffect` is that code inside `useEffect` will be executed on the first render, but the updated state will be set to `selectedMenuItem` only on the second render, so there will be some flash of the first state.

The correct approach is to use `function` as the argument of `useState` as this code will be executed only on the first render:

`const [selectedMenuItem, setSelectedMenuItem] = useState(() => (items.find((item) => item.route === router.pathname))!.key);`

Comment: Just be aware that `useState` doesn't have a dependency array, so if `router.pathname` can update you would want to avoid the function variant.   IOW: make sure this function is pure.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you, in this case `useEffect` comes handy